# Horizontal scrollbar appearing on display: table element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page layout like this:

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.table-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 100%;
}

.cell-left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 240px;
}

.cell-right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1126px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="cell-left"></div>
    <div class="cell-right">

    /* Some really long content */

    </div>
</div>
```

When a content in .cell-right becomes long enough for browser to display vertical scrollbar it also adds horizontal scrollbar which really ruins my layout. Problem goes away if I put 100% width on .table-wrapper but it also shrinks both cells which I do not want. I must have fixed widths on all 3 elements to do proper tweaks for responsive design which project requires. Also both cells need to span across document height.

Funny thing is that Internet explorer 11 does not have this problem but both Firefox and Chrome do. What can I do to prevent horizontal scrollbar appearing?

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that I'm testing this on screen resolution of 1366x768. If you wanna test this yourself on your own screen resolution just change the numbers.

Here's the fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zddm6asz/1/show/

Here is another one for 1920x1200:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zddm6asz/2/show/

Comment: Which scrollbar ? http://jsfiddle.net/zddm6asz/

Comment: Try testing it outside jsFiddle, it doesn't show up there

Comment: **NOTE** the frame url is http://fiddle.jshell.net/zddm6asz/show/

Comment: Here's proper example http://fiddle.jshell.net/zddm6asz/1/show/

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See my first comment under this answer, before trying out this.

If you add

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

for the `.cell-left` and `.cell-right`, then this should prevent the cells from getting a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I set up a little fiddle and just reduced the overall width a bit, so it can fit in a screen better, if you want. [http://jsfiddle.net/zz5rr41L/3/] The only horizontal scrollbar I can see, doesn't come from the cell, it is generated by the body itself, if the table doesn't fit into your screen. Therefore `overflow-x: hidden;` for a cell will not help thats true.

Comment: It doesn't add horizontal bar to a cell, it adds it to a whole page which doesn't make sense since table itself doesn't exceed screen width.

Comment: Referring to your edit of the question. If you have a screen resolution of 1366 wide, than a element with a width of 1366px will the screen width. Browser are not always maximized, and from the 1366px screen width you also have to subtract the width of the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I did, I had to subtract 17px which is width of the scrollbar. Internet explorer doesn't have that problem because it puts scrollbars on top of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with a horizontal scroll bar appearing when I was using display:table-cell; for some elements. The scroll bar was applied to the entire page but applying overflow:hidden; to the containing element of these cells solved the problem. In your case that would be applying overflow:hidden; to .table-wrapper.

Also, you may not want to set a pixel width to your table-wrapper. Why not just set it up as a percentage with a max-width if possible? This is especially true is you are attempting a responsive design.